# Reduce the width of div automatically by the addition of contents to another div

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I might need a bit of help here, if you see the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnduqh9r/) you will understand.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">Green</div>
    <div class="b">Yellow</div>
</div>
```

I want to know if I could `reduce the green box` width automatically if `I increase the content in the yellow box`. I want it to be done purely using HTML and CSS. If it's not possible I will work around with it with a script.

Counting on you guys.....

**EDIT**

The yellow div should not jump down by the addition of content. The green one should be reduced

Comment: And yea one more thing the yellow div should not jump down by the addition of content.The green one should reduce.

Comment: r u looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/mnduqh9r/1/

Comment: No buddy the green div width is fixed with percentage and the red div is a fixed width

Comment: look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/mnduqh9r/2/ I have fixed 70% and 30% width.

Comment: Suresh this is correct but i have to use float in my work....cant avoid float.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was to make a `fixed right div` and a `dynamic left div`. I do that by `floating right` the `right div` but I place it first.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="b">Yellow Yellow Yellow</div>
    <div class="a">Green Green</div>
</div>
```

Then some simple changes in `CSS`:

```
.a {
    border:2px solid green;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.b {
    float:right;
    border:2px solid yellow;
}
```

Now increase the number of "Yellow" and "Green" so you can see the difference, for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hm0bqsaL/

http://jsfiddle.net/t47ehnv0/

http://jsfiddle.net/0rgohyve/

http://jsfiddle.net/6mcL5e7y/

Comment: Hi buddy, I have to give float to a class.i dont have choice because i have some elements and margin and stuff in a class.anyways i am accepting your answer please show me a work around